# IIS RewriteBase for an .htaccess

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite

In IIS, `RewriteBase` is not working. So the below `.htaccess` rule has been converted as an IIS web config. But in IIS it is giving 400 Bad Request error. What do I need to correct?

Htaccess Rule

```
RewriteRule api/(.*)$ api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

IIS Converted Rule

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="api/(.*)$"/>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php?request={R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: # IIS Converted Rule
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="api/(.*)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php?request={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
 </rule>

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Enable FRT and read what it says.

Comment: could you please share what you rea passing in URL? you enabled the append query string which adds the query string if you entered in URL. also please clarify what is your exact requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `RewriteBase` directive is set like this:

```
RewriteBase /subdir
```

Then you simply need to append this "prefix" to the start of the target URL (ie. `RewriteRule` *substitution* or `url` attribute value in the IIS directive). Specifically, it should be prefixed only to *relative* substitution strings.

For example:

```
RewriteRule api/(.*)$ /subdir/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

In other words:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="/subdir/api.php?request={R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
```

If `RewriteBase /` is set then just prefix with a single slash, eg. `url="/api.php?request={R:1}"`

That's all that `RewriteBase` directive does. It sets the URL-prefix for relative path substitutions when used in a *directory* context.